# How to parse JSON schedule timestamps data with Python 3 into a list of days & times per day

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, formatting

I have a data sourcing project I thought would be good for a first foray into Python. I have managed to work out the downloading and file writing (largely with info from this site), but after months of on and off tinkering, I have been unable to figure out the most important part - parsing the schedule data into the daily list of times format that I want.

The end goal is a batch of txt files with the data in the format I need to copy & paste into graphics software, eliminating the tedious manual processing step I have been doing every week on data received by email from multiple sources and in multiple formats.

CODE (problem section, print instead write to file):

```
# get showtimes data from the local JSON files & write to txt file (eventually)
def ShowtimesParseJSON ():
    
        import os
        import json 
        import datetime
        import time
        from datetime import timezone
        from dateutil import tz

        with open('showtimes.json') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            print ('\n')

            # loop to print each title, rating
            for title in data['titles']:
                print ('\n')
                print (title.get('title'),"(",title.get('rating'),")")
                print ('-------------------------------------')

                latest_day = ""
             
                # TO DO: Limit enumerate & write to Friday->Thursday
                for idx, perf in enumerate(title['perf'], start=1):
                    this_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(perf.get('start'), tz=timezone.utc)
                    # exact same result with or without the if below ??
                    if(this_day != latest_day):
                        latest_day = this_day
                        #day of week
                        print (f'{this_day:%a (%b %d)}', end="\t")
                    #daily times
                    print (f'{this_day:%#I:%M}')
                print (f'Total shows: ', idx)
                print ('-------------------------------------')    

ShowtimesParseJSON ()
```

JSON (showtimes.json edited to remove extra fields):

```
{
    "titles":
    [
        {
            "id": 822,
            "title": "80 FOR BRADY",
            "longTitle": "80 FOR BRADY",
            "rating": "PG",
            "perf":
            [
                {
                    "id": 97632,
                    "start": 1677848400
                },
                {
                    "id": 97633,
                    "start": 1677855600
                },
                {
                    "id": 97504,
                    "start": 1677942300
                },
                {
                    "id": 97510,
                    "start": 1677949200
                },
                {
                    "id": 97683,
                    "start": 1678044000
                },
                {
                    "id": 97710,
                    "start": 1678051200
                },
                {
                    "id": 97732,
                    "start": 1678107600
                },
                {
                    "id": 97720,
                    "start": 1678114800
                },
                {
                    "id": 97748,
                    "start": 1678201200
                },
                {
                    "id": 97761,
                    "start": 1678224900
                },
                {
                    "id": 97788,
                    "start": 1678280400
                },
                {
                    "id": 97776,
                    "start": 1678287600
                },
                {
                    "id": 97816,
                    "start": 1678366800
                },
                {
                    "id": 97804,
                    "start": 1678374000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I admit, I have forgotten a number of attempts at solving the day/times looping issue since I took a break for a while after finding a workaround which is no longer available. There was an attempt at using a while loop that upset my computer greatly. And I do have some PHP code that parses the JSON and tried to 'translate' that into Python with no luck.

I think it has something to do with the nesting/looping the timestamp twice but I haven't worked it out yet and I'm getting very tired of the manual data cleanup every week. Would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

What I am trying for format wise (from Fri to Thu, with a list of times for each day):

```
80 FOR BRADY ( PG )
-------------------------------------
Fri (Mar 03)    1:00 - 3:00
Sat (Mar 04)    3:05 - 5:00
...
Thu (Mar 09)    1:00 - 3:00
Total shows:  14
-------------------------------------
```

What I am actually getting is each time with the day:

```
80 FOR BRADY ( PG )
-------------------------------------
Fri (Mar 03)    1:00
Fri (Mar 03)    3:00
Sat (Mar 04)    3:05
...
Thu (Mar 09)    3:00
Total shows:  14
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to *group* the days and then join the time:

```py
import json
import datetime
from datetime import timezone
from itertools import groupby

def ShowtimesParseJSON():
    all_data = []

    with open("your_data.json") as file:
        data = json.load(file)

        # loop to print each title, rating
        for title in data["titles"]:
            for perf in title["perf"]:
                this_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                    perf.get("start"), tz=timezone.utc
                )
                day = f"{this_day:%a (%b %d)}"
                t = f"{this_day:%#I:%M}"

                all_data.append((day, t))

            print(title.get('title'),"(",title.get('rating'),")")
            print('-------------------------------------')
            for _, g in groupby(all_data, lambda t: t[0]):
                g = list(g)
                print(g[0][0] + '\t' + ' - '.join(t for _, t in g))
            print(f'Total shows: ', len(title["perf"]))
            print('-------------------------------------')


ShowtimesParseJSON()
```

Prints:

```
80 FOR BRADY ( PG )
-------------------------------------
Fri (Mar 03)    01:00 - 03:00
Sat (Mar 04)    03:05 - 05:00
Sun (Mar 05)    07:20 - 09:20
Mon (Mar 06)    01:00 - 03:00
Tue (Mar 07)    03:00 - 09:35
Wed (Mar 08)    01:00 - 03:00
Thu (Mar 09)    01:00 - 03:00
Total shows:  14
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: How would this be expanded to limit by title? FilmA is fine, but for FilmB after the title it prints the weekly times for FilmA and FilmB and so on. By the last film, all of the weekly times for all of the titles are listed beneath the title.

Answer (score 0):

A less professional approach without modifying your code too much and following your idea of checking the day before and after in order to format correctly:

```
import json 
import datetime
from datetime import timezone

def ShowtimesParseJSON ():
    with open('showtimes.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        print ('\n')

        for title in data['titles']:
            print ('\n')
            print (title.get('title'),"(",title.get('rating'),")")
            print ('-------------------------------------')

            for idx, (perf, prev_perf,next_perf) in enumerate(zip([None]+title['perf']+[None],[None,None]+title['perf'],title['perf']+[None,None])):
                if perf == None:
                        continue
                perf_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(perf.get('start'), tz=timezone.utc)
                if prev_perf != None:
                    prev_perf_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(prev_perf.get('start'), tz=timezone.utc) 
                else:
                    prev_perf_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(perf.get('start'), tz=timezone.utc)
                if next_perf != None:
                    next_perf_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_perf.get('start'), tz=timezone.utc)
                else:
                    next_perf_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(perf.get('start'), tz=timezone.utc)
                if perf_time.date() != prev_perf_time.date() or idx == 1:
                    print (f'{perf_time:%a (%b %d)}', end="\t")
                if perf_time.date() == next_perf_time.date() and idx != len(title['perf']):   
                    print (f'{perf_time:%#I:%M}', end=" - ")
                else:
                    print (f'{perf_time:%#I:%M}')
            print (f'Total shows: ', idx-1)
            print ('-------------------------------------')    

ShowtimesParseJSON ()
```

Prints:

```
80 FOR BRADY ( PG )
-------------------------------------
Fri (Mar 03)    1:00 - 3:00
Sat (Mar 04)    3:05 - 5:00
Sun (Mar 05)    7:20 - 9:20
Mon (Mar 06)    1:00 - 3:00
Tue (Mar 07)    3:00 - 9:35
Wed (Mar 08)    1:00 - 3:00
Thu (Mar 09)    1:00 - 3:00
Total shows:  14
-------------------------------------
```